# Network setting in docker host and container using user defined bridge network, where ping fails from host to container

Tags: docker, networking, containers, docker-network

I have to create the container with ip 192.168.31.11. So, I used the user-defined bridge network and created mynet as:

```
docker network create \
                --driver=bridge \
                --subnet=192.168.31.0/24 \
                --ip-range=192.168.31.0/24 \
                --gateway=192.168.31.1 \
                mynet
```

Now, using the command

```
docker run --network mynet --name ca1 --ip 192.168.31.11 -itd -p 8002:80 -v $PWD:/build sc5
```

I have created the container.
The docker host has now below ifconfig:

```
br-426eea85deb3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.31.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  **broadcast 192.168.31.255**
        inet6 fe80::42:cfff:fe3e:d01b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:cf:3e:d0:1b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 586 (586.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:58:0e:02:97  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.31.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  **broadcast 192.168.31.255**
        inet6 fe80::202:6bff:fe21:463c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:02:6b:21:46:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1440 (1.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65  bytes 3216 (3.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf000000-df01ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536  metric 1
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 509  bytes 37544 (36.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 509  bytes 37544 (36.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethda02539: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet6 fe80::f072:a4ff:fe51:18bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f2:72:a4:51:18:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1172 (1.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but, when I do ping to container from host to container the ping fails!!.

But when I change the docker host network setting using */etc/sysconfig/network*, the host ip from *192.168.31.101* to *192.168.11.101*. The ping from host to container is successful!!.

I am not able to understand what is stopping the ping to succeed in first case!?.

I have tried the same on ubuntu machine by creating the mynet with same broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx that of host and container br-xxxx broacast. In this Ubuntu machine the ping succeeds!!

the ubuntu case details are as below:

ifconfig:

```
br-7b1ed572fe95: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  **broadcast 10.0.2.255**
        inet6 fe80::42:bff:fe9d:d6eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:0b:9d:d6:eb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97  bytes 12767 (12.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61  bytes 6739 (6.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:11:f0:da:29  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  **broadcast 10.0.2.255**
        inet6 fe80::365a:ddd:b83c:4abe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:82:79:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14188  bytes 15705468 (15.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3415  bytes 264989 (264.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1727  bytes 141367 (141.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1727  bytes 141367 (141.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth11ef32e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::b014:feff:feaa:cea3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b2:14:fe:aa:ce:a3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97  bytes 14125 (14.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87  bytes 9899 (9.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am confused and no idea why ping fails in 192.xx.xx.xx case that succeeds in case of Ubuntu on Windows VM?

Is that I am missing some thing with docker host?

Any help or guidance will much appreciated. Please let me know if more information or details needed further to understand the same to suggest on something.
Thanks,

Comment: You said that you've tried the same on an ubuntu machine. What machine is experiencing the problem? Are you running docker in a VM? Is this on a mac or a windows machine for example?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, thanks for reply. in first case, I am running on embedded product using the x86 intel chip running the Linux ( with Timesys). Yes, it is Windows machine with VM on which I have tried with Ubuntu in later ubuntu case.

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to manually set container IP addresses, or send ICMP packets to containers.  (You don't do either of these things for non-Docker processes.)  In most cases you should ignore the container-private IP addresses entirely, since they only work at all from the same host and then when that host is native-Linux.  Is there a higher-level goal you're trying to achieve with this setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Yes David. I need the container with that particular private ip only. Can't use the default the ip assigned by 172.x.x.x range. I will be using this 192.168.31.11 to launch the html page and further do the user interaction to receive input and store them using volumes, to be brief. ip has inter-dependencies as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked thoroughly, the VM has managed the routing with same destination address and with enpxsx and br-xxx.
But on my hardware, the routing is getting clashed when have same destination address in route.

The route command details:

```
$route -vn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.31.31        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
192.168.31.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-7b1ed572fe95
192.168.31.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

So, there is 192.168.31.0 destination with enp0s3 and br-xxxx too. Which blocking the routing!!. To verify the same I have created another user defined bridge network with **192.168.11**.x setting and it works as expected.
So, host and container are trying to same hw type ether with destination address 192.168.31.0 using **Iface ethX and br-xxxx**.
So unlikely can make this container work with ip **192.168.31.11**. ( or need to change the host ip **192.168.11.X** )

Or is there any thing I can do to make work, with same 192.168.31.x ip on host and container(s) having 192.168.31.x?